# Need to search a value in json in one array and provide output from another array using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a below pattern json.

```
{
"a": [{
"metadata":{ "name":"raj"},
"status":[{
"state":
{  "sleeping":
  { "started":"2020-05-11T14:49:04Z",
    "ID":"1002"}
 }},{
"state": 
 { "sleeping":
   { "started":"2020-05-11T14:49:04Z",
     "ID":"1002"}
 }}],
"phase":"sleeping"},

{
"metadata":{ "name":"tom"},
"status":[{
"state":
{  "sleeping":
  { "started":"2020-05-11T14:49:04Z",
    "ID":"1002"}
 }},{
"state": 
 { "sleeping":
   { "started":"2020-05-11T14:49:04Z",
     "ID":"1002"}
 }}],
"phase":"sleeping"}]}
```

I need to the output using jq to filter the name(.metadata.name) for those items in the list that have the state(.status[].state) as sleeping in below format
Name ID
raj
So far I was successful to select the state in sleeping.
jq '.a[].status[]| select(.state | has("terminated"))
However I am unable to combine the name and generate the output.
Sorry if sounds silly and thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the invocation:

```
jq -r -f sleeping.jq pattern.json
```

where sleeping.jq is:

```
.a[]
| .metadata.name as $raj
| select( any(.status[].state; has("sleeping")) )
| "Name ID \($raj)"
```

the result is:

```
Name ID raj
Name ID tom
```

#### Solution to amended question

```
.a[]
| .metadata.name as $raj
| .status[].state
| select( has("sleeping"))
| "Name ID \($raj) \(.sleeping.ID)"
```

Comment: I am so sorry there was some format issue with output. It must be as below
Name   ID
Raj        1002